# "Attribute name must contain word characters only" при использовании русских букв в ActiveForm

Tags: yii2, activeform

Приветствую! Помогите разобраться.. при создании контактной формы с помощью ActiveForm в yii2 решила поменять английский язык на русский и тут выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Attribute name must contain word characters only.

1. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php at line 2128

    2119 * @param Model $model the model object
    2120 * @param string $attribute the attribute name or expression
    2121 * @return string the generated input name
    2122 * @throws InvalidParamException if the attribute name contains non-word characters.
    2123 */
    2124 public static function getInputName($model, $attribute)
    2125 {
    2126    $formName = $model->formName();
    2127    if (!preg_match('/(^|.*\])([\w\.]+)(\[.*|$)/', $attribute, $matches)) {
    2128        throw new InvalidParamException('Attribute name must contain word characters only.');
    2129    }
    2130    $prefix = $matches[1];
    2131    $attribute = $matches[2];
    2132    $suffix = $matches[3];
    2133    if ($formName === '' && $prefix === '') {
    2134        return $attribute . $suffix;
    2135    } elseif ($formName !== '') {
    2136        return $formName . $prefix . "[$attribute]" . $suffix;
    2137    } else {

2. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php at line 1263 – yii\helpers\BaseHtml::getInputName(app\models\ContactForm, 'ваше имя')
3. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php at line 1313 – yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeInput('text', app\models\ContactForm, 'ваше имя', ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => true])
4. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php at line 395 – yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeTextInput(app\models\ContactForm, 'ваше имя', ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => true])
5. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\views\site\contact.php at line 29 – yii\widgets\ActiveField::textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => true])

23            <div class="row-content buffer even clear-after">
24                <div class="section-title"><h3>Контакты</h3></div>
25                <p>Техническая поддержка проекта Money-day</p>
26                <div class="column nine">
27                    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
28 
29                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ваше имя')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
30 
31                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ваш Email') ?>
32 
33                    <?= $form->field($model, 'тема') ?>
34 
35                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ваше сообщение')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

6. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php at line 328 – require('C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains...')
7. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php at line 250 – yii\base\View::renderPhpFile('C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains...', ['model' => app\models\ContactForm])
8. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php at line 152 – yii\base\View::renderFile('C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains...', ['model' => app\models\ContactForm], app\controllers\SiteController)
9. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 381 – yii\base\View::render('contact', ['model' => app\models\ContactForm], app\controllers\SiteController)
10. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\controllers\SiteController.php at line 180 – yii\base\Controller::render('contact', ['model' => app\models\ContactForm])
174175176177178179180181182183184185186

174        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
175            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
176 
177            return $this->refresh();
178        }
179        return $this->render('contact', [
180            'model' => $model,
181        ]);
182    }
183 
184    /**
185     * Displays about page.
186     *

11. app\controllers\SiteController::actionContact()
```

вот код из contact.php:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'Ваше имя')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'Ваш Email') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'Тема') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'Ваше сообщение')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
                ]) ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
                </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Вот код из web.php:

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
```

Вот код из ContactForm.php:

```
class ContactForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;
    public $verifyCode;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        [['Ваше имя', 'Ваш Email', 'Тема', 'Ваше сообщение'], 'required'],
        // email has to be a valid email address
        ['email', 'email'],
        // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
        ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'verifyCode' => 'Введите следующий код безопасности',
    ];
}

/**
 * Sends an email to the specified email address using the information collected by this model.
 * @param string $email the target email address
 * @return bool whether the model passes validation
 */
public function contact($email)
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setTextBody($this->body)
            ->send();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Добрый день. А что это за странная строка `[['Ваше имя', 'Ваш Email', 'Тема', 'Ваше сообщение'], 'required'],`?

Comment: @slo_nik Было всё по умолчанию..)) Я думала что проблема в ней и прописала так.. но проблема не решилась и я обратно исправила на [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],

Comment: Извините, но кто Вас надоумил это сделать?)))

Comment: @slo_nik Я просто только учусь и с этим никогда не сталкивалась.. Сама себя и надоумила)) Да я понимаю что нужно усердно читать документацию, чтоб больше таких нелепых ошибок не было..

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html

http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/tag/Yii2

Comment: @slo_nik Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте в форме

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['palceholder' => 'Ваше имя', 'autofocus' => true]) ?>
```

Остальные поля так же

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получилось))

Comment: Пожалуйста, но не получилось, а устранена грубейшая ошибка)